# Occulus Rift video playback in Unity 3D

Tags: video, unity-game-engine

I am currently working on an R&D project which involves video playback in Unity 3D to be deployed on the Oculus Rift. Current issues using the native unity movie texture includes a substantial fps drop in the OVR and also in the unity Editor. I have tried a few of the video players in the unity asset store and still no luck.

Can anyone point me in the right direction regarding video playback in unity 3D and OVR?

Comment: Can you add a Screenshot of your profiler ?

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all you have to convert your video in ogv file.
2. Create a plan and drag & drop this to create a movietexture.

This worked for me

It's maybe not a problem of MovieTexture so you can also try to **remove VSync**.

Oculus it's quite a new technology and need a good PC even for simple things.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but that didn't solve. I am using a high-end PC for this test.